# How can I add a number to a variable to which I assigned a number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
var offset;
offset = localStorage.getItem('test.MenuList.Offset.' + examID + "." + level) || 0;
offset += 100;
```

When I use the debugger this offset now has 0100. I want it to add like a number not a string. How can I do this?

**Please note** I changed the question slightly because I realized I was getting the value from local storage. I assume this returns a string. But I am still not sure how to solve this.

Comment: Works fine for me -- http://jsfiddle.net/gQLVW/

Comment: David - Sorry. I updated the question. I think this is my problem. I get the value from localStorage.

Comment: Sorry David. Please see my change to the question. If I do: offset = "0"; then it gives "0100" :-(

Comment: Anything inside quotes is a string, and adding "0" and 100 would be the same as adding "B" and 100, which would give you "B100" etc.

Answer (score 2):

<s>The code you gave won't do that. I assume</s> your value in your actual code is a numeric string. <s>If so,</s> the `+` will behave as a *string concatenation* operator, so you must convert the value to a number before using `+`.

You can do that with [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat).

```
var offset = localStorage.getItem('test.MenuList.Offset.' + examID + "." + level);

offset = parseFloat(offset) || 0;
```

---

Or in most cases, you can simply use the unary version of `+` to do the conversion.

```
offset = +offset || 0;
```